# How do I shorten a one line if statement in ruby that only executes if field is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, coding-style

I have the following `if` statement that fills a field with the result of a function, if the function doesn't return empty.

I think i've seen examples before where the empty check and the function can be combined in the `if`without me having to repeat the whole function again in the condition.

I'm looking for newb DRY advice please!

```
icons = page.search("theicons").to_s if !page.search("theicons").to_s.empty?
```

Comment: why `page.search("theicons").to_s` needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is something wrong with

```
theicons = page.search("theicons").to_s
icons = theicons unless theicons.empty?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails you could shorten it to this:

```
icons = page.search("theicons").to_s.presence || icons
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical operators:

```
icons = (page.search('theicons') || default_value).to_s
```

Comment: empty string evaluates to `true`

Comment: I saw this first. Now it's fixed.

Comment: if `page.search` returns the empty string then the field still gets overwritten with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
icons = page.search("theicons").to_s.present? && page.search("theicons").to_s
```

Note: `present?` is a rails helper.

Comment: I don't think we want to call page.search more than once.

Answer (score 0):

```
icons = page.search("theicons") unless page.search("theicons").present?
```

or

```
icons ||= page.search("theicons")
```